# Does the propagation model for a visible light communication system differ based on transmitter?

Tags: visible-light

Would the channel of a visible light communication (VLC) system differ based on the type of the transmitter that is used.

in literature I stumble upon reading which explains signal attenuation as a function of the wavelength, that means color. However, I wonder would this be true for any type of transmitter.

Let's assume the attenuation coefficient is `X` for rainy weather. Does this `X` apply to a system which has LED as a transmitter, as well as to a system which has a light bulb as transmitter. Assuming both the LED and the light bulb emit the same color (same wavelength) with same optical power.

Feel free to add any comments or references regarding channel modeling for visible light communication

Comment: _Color_ and _power spectrum_ are two different phenomena.  The power spectrum is the physical reality, while color describes how we perceive it.  You can have light sources with two very different spectra that both appear to be the same color (Google _metamerism_).

Answer (score 0):

> Let's assume the attenuation coefficient is X for rainy weather. Does this X apply to a system which has LED as a transmitter, as well as to a system which has a light bulb as transmitter. Assuming both the LED and the light bulb emit the same color (same wavelength) with same optical power.

Yes, the attenuation coefficient for, say, 650 nm is the same whether the source of the 650 nm light is a laser, an LED, or an incandescent bulb.

However, different sources tend to emit different spectra.

For example, no incandescent bulb can emit only 650 nm. It will emit a very broad spectrum with substantial energy from maybe 400 nm out into the IR at maybe 2000 or 3000 nm (actually it will emit something like a blackbody spectrum with output at all wavelengths, but most of the energy is likely to be in this range).

An LED with main emission at 650 nm might actually be emitting everything from 600 to 700 nm.

A "650 nm" laser source might just be emitting 648 nm +/- 1 nm.

So to find the attenuation for the sources with broad emission spectra, you'd have to integrate to find the net attenuation from the emission spectrum and the material attenuation profile.